# Python download a full web page (Including CSS)

Tags: python, download, scrapy

I have a script running with Scrapy and Splash which pulls various data from a site, but am now trying to find a way of making an offline copy of each page too.

I have tried the following with Scrapy:

```
def parse(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

And this with Urllib:

```
def parse(self, response):
    url = response.url
    file_name = 'aaa.html'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

Both of which work fine, but only download the HTML to file. I require the full page (with CSS included) - so is there any way of doing this, similar to replicating saving as 'Web Page, Complete' when manually saving sites using google chrome?

I suspect something like Selenium could, but guess it would be too slow for my application (which requires 100's, sometimes 1000's of URL's). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use BeautifulSoup or Scrapy to go through the downloaded html and extract things with the a, src tags

more specifically for example the css will be in the following tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
```

and then download the file in the href content your coding will need to be a lot more complex

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying this and am currently stuck on editing the response before writing it out as a HTML - I get the error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`  when using the replace function. Do you have any advice on a way around this please? Thanks.